# Is there anything similar to Cal/CardDAV in android

Tags: android, ios, synchronization, caldav, carddav

I have an app that has been designed for iOS. I have the CalDAV and CardDAV feature as part it that is used to sync the events and contacts from my app to the device. I'm now creating an android app and would like to know if there is something similar. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i could use a CalendarProvider and a ContactProvider but would be good if someone could throw some light on this.

Answer (score 0):

There are free applications available for Android, called CalDAV-Sync and CardDAV-Sync. They install its provider, so default Android UI is used for calendars and contacts management.